# Magento collection - need to amend to make query to make it AND rather than OR

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the following Collection in Magento :-

```
    $this->addFieldToFilter(array('postcode', 'organisation_name'),array(
        array('eq' => $postcode),
        array('like' => $lastname. '%')
    ));

    return $this;
```

This returns a query as follows:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`organisation_id`, `main_table`.`organisation_id`,
`main_table`.`organisation_type_id`, `main_table`.`organisation_name`, `main_table`.`street`, 
`main_table`.`town`, `main_table`.`county`, `main_table`.`country`, `main_table`.`postcode` FROM  
`organisation` AS `main_table` WHERE ((postcode = 'AA11AA') 
OR (organisation_name LIKE 'jones%')) 
LIMIT 1
```

How do I amend this so it becomes an AND rather than an OR in the SQL query returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$this->addFieldToFilter('postcode',array('eq' => $postcode))
     ->addFieldToFilter('organisation_name',array('like' => $lastname. '%'))
```

Comment: how can we use `addFilter($field, $value, $type = 'and')` for AND condition ? Is it possible ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy. I don't know if `addFilter` works for all collection types. It it better to use `addFieldToFilter` or `addAttributeToFilter` depending on the collection type. First one is for flat entities, second one for EAV entities.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I know about the other two filters, but was just curious if we can specify `AND` / `OR` condition in any of the filter option

Comment: Thanks Marius you are quite the Magento guru on here :)

Comment: @Zabs, aww shocks...you make me blush. :)